# Stack Overflow Default Responses when Replying to Answers

Tags: discussion, support

I see sometimes when scrolling through questions that a comment has been added that looks like a "default response" telling the user that their question isn't up to par with SO standards. It gives them a few links to help them ask a better formed question.

Now is there a complied list of these "default responses" or are they all individual and based off what the particular user has created.

Comment: They're mostly just the same as the flags text, you can use a tool like [this](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) to make posting them easier

Comment: Like [this](https://pastebin.com/Q3H7zcSn)?

Comment: YES exactly like that! Is there a wiki page or a complied list somewhere? I couldn't provide an example because for the life of me I couldn't find one of these default responses... of course right?

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/Useful_Comments is a short list of comment that can be used

Comment: @DragandDrop thats it. Please put that as an answer and i'll mark it accordingly!

Comment: There's a user script somewhere that lets you add in auto comments that you can insert with a single click though I can't seem to find it right now. EDIT: [Found it](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)